# Can hive partition point to multiple directories within main partition?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hive

I have folder structure like below

```
gs://bucket_name/data/db_name.db/table_name/color=red/txn_dt=2023-01-01/.bin_1
gs://bucket_name/data/db_name.db/table_name/color=red/txn_dt=2023-01-01/.bin_2
gs://bucket_name/data/db_name.db/table_name/color=red/txn_dt=2023-01-01/.bin_3
gs://bucket_name/data/db_name.db/table_name/color=red/txn_dt=2023-01-01/part1.snappy.orc
gs://bucket_name/data/db_name.db/table_name/color=red/txn_dt=2023-01-02/.bin_1
gs://bucket_name/data/db_name.db/table_name/color=red/txn_dt=2023-01-02/.bin_2
gs://bucket_name/data/db_name.db/table_name/color=red/txn_dt=2023-01-02/part2.snappy.orc
```

I want a external hive table on top of above location which is partitioned by color and txn_dt columns. I need txn_dt partition to point to all folders inside the bucket that starts with .bin and ignore the actual files within that partition (Essentially giving me count of files in each partition under .bin)

I get the count from spark shell by running below command

`spark.read.orc("gs://bucket_name/data/db_name.db/table_name/color=red/txn_dt=*/.bin*").count`

But I can only add one bin folder per txn_dt partition since regex throws below error

```
use db;

ALTER TABLE tb PARTITION(color='red',txn_dt='2023-01-01') SET LOCATION "gs://bucket_name/data/db_name.db/table_name/color=red/txn_dt=2023-01-01/.bin_1";

ALTER TABLE tb PARTITION(color='red',txn_dt='2023-01-02') SET LOCATION "gs://bucket_name/data/db_name.db/table_name/color=red/txn_dt=2023-01-02/.bin_1";
```

The above works but I miss out on .bin_2, .bin_3 parititions for txn_dt=2023-01-01 and .bin_1, .bin_2 parititions for txn_dt=2023-01-02

I tried something like below

```
ALTER TABLE tb PARTITION(color='red',txn_dt='2023-01-01') SET LOCATION "gs://bucket_name/data/db_name.db/table_name/color=red/txn_dt=2023-01-01/.bin*";

ALTER TABLE tb PARTITION(color='red',txn_dt='2023-01-02') SET LOCATION "gs://bucket_name/data/db_name.db/table_name/color=red/txn_dt=2023-01-02/.bin*";
```

That resulted in below failures

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: listStatus(hadoopPath: gs://bucket_name/data/db_name.db/table_name/color=red/txn_dt=2023-01-02/.bin*): 'gs://bucket_name/data/db_name.db/table_name/color=red/txn_dt=2023-01-02/.bin*' does not exist.
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.generateSplitsInfo(OrcInputFormat.java:1673)
        ... 15 more
```

Comment: I dont think alter statement can work line this. Use sub partition to partition the table first and then re-insert data. Create a new table with desired partition `PARTITIONED BY(COLOR STRING, txndata date)`. Then load into this table from original and drop original.